# How to merge a map made with ggplot and a bubble plot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can produce a map of Europe and the bubble plot that would layer on top of the map but I do not know how to merge these together successfully. Will someone please help me do this? :)

Here is the code I have used to create the two separate components:

```
    library(cowplot)
    library(googleway)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(ggrepel)
    library(ggspatial)
    library(sf)
    library(rnaturalearth)
    library(rnaturalearthdata)    
    library("ggplot2")
    theme_set(theme_bw())
    library("sf")
    library("rnaturalearth")
    library("rnaturalearthdata")
    
    world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
    class(world)
     
    ## Produces the map of Europe ##
    ggplot(data = world) +
    geom_sf() +
    coord_sf(xlim = c(-15, 55), ylim = c(34, 71), expand = FALSE)
   
             
    cities <- read.csv("cities1_R.csv")
    df <- cities
             
    df$Country <- as.factor(df$Country)
             
    head(df[ , c("City", "Country", "Latitude", "Longitude", "No..of.Samples")], 28)
             
    ## Produces Bubbles plot ##               
    ggplot(df, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude)) + 
    geom_polygon(df, aes(x= Longitude, y= Latitude, group=group), fill="grey", alpha=0.3)
    geom_point(aes(color = Country, size = No..of.Samples), alpha = 0.9) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("#FF3300", "#0066CC", "#FFFF00", "#CC0066", "#9933CC", 
    "#00FFFF", "#FF9900", "#000000", "#00CC00", 
    "#999999", "#FF6666", "#FF3399", "#669933", 
    "#000099", "#6666FF", "#003300", "#66FF33", "#660066", "#FF99CC", 
    "#333333", "#CC33FF", "#CC6699", "#663300", "#330033", "#666600", "#CCFF00", "#CC9900", 
    "#990033")) +
    scale_size(breaks = c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175), range = c(0.5, 12))  # Adjust 
    the range of points size
```

The size of the bubbles is dependent on the no. of samples in the cities data. This is the table:
[cities1_R.csv file showing the data in a table format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ReWy.png)

| City | Country | Latitude | Longitude | No..of.Samples |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AMSTERDAM | NETHERLANDS | 52.37403 | 4.88969 | 22 |
| 2 | BARI | ITALY | 41.11148 | 3.53390 | 196 |
| 3 | BUDAPEST | HUNGARY | 47.49801 | 19.03991 |
| 4 | LONDON | UNITED KINGDOM | 51.50853 | -0.12574 |
| 5 | BERLIN | GERMANY | 52.52437 | 13.41053 |
| 6 | COPENHAGEN | DENMARK | 55.67594 | 12.56553 |
| 7 | LISBOA | PORTUGAL | 38.71667 | -9.13333 |
| 8 | WARSZAW | POLAND | 52.22977 | 21.01178 |
| 9 | DUBLIN | IRELAND | 53.33306 | -6.24889 |
| 10 | LJUBLJANA | SLOVENIA | 46.05108 | 14.50513 |
| 11 | BRUXELLES | BELGIUM | 50.85045 | 4.34878 |
| 12 | PARIS | FRANCE | 48.85341 | 2.34880 |
| 13 | WIEN | AUSTRIA | 48.20849 | 16.37208 |
| 14 | ASTURIAS | SPAIN | 43.36140 | -5.85930 |
| 15 | ATHENS | GREECE | 37.98380 | 23.72750 |
| 16 | STOCKHOLM | SWEDEN | 59.32930 | 18.06860 |
| 17 | SOFIA | BULGARIA | 42.69770 | 23.32190 |
| 18 | ZAGREB | CROATIA | 45.81500 | 15.98190 |
| 19 | NICOSIA | CYPRUS | 35.18560 | 33.38230 |
| 20 | PRAGUE | CZECH REPUBLIC | 50.07550 | 14.43780 |
| 21 | TALLINN | ESTONIA | 59.43700 | 24.75360 |
| 22 | HELSINKI | FINLAND | 60.16990 | 24.93840 |
| 23 | RIGA | LATVIA | 56.94960 | 24.10520 |
| 24 | VILNIUS | LITHUANIA | 54.68720 | 25.27970 |
| 25 | LUXEMBOURG CITY | LUXEMBOURG | 49.81530 | 6.12960 |
| 26 | VALLETTA | MALTA | 35.89890 | 14.51460 |
| 27 | BUCHAREST | ROMANIA | 44.42680 | 26.10250 |
| 28 | BRATISLAVA | SLOVAKIA | 48.14860 | 17.10770 |

This is the map of Europe I have produced:
[Map of Europe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PnKr.png)

This is the bubble plot I have produced:
[Bubble ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uj9o.png)

If someone knows how to merge the two ggplots that would be amazing. I tried using the geom_polygon function but I couldn't get it to work. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please make it into a reproducible example? If you add a hard-coded version of your dataframe loaded from the CSV with just a couple of rows it would make it a lot easier for anyone to run your code,

Comment: Is that what you meant? I have edited the post^.

Comment: Not quite, but I added a quick example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I added a rough version of a repex with just 3 cities, but this should work with your entire data.

```
library(cowplot)
library(googleway)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(ggspatial)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)    
library("ggplot2")
theme_set(theme_bw())
library("sf")
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")

x = "1 AMSTERDAM NETHERLANDS 52.37403 4.88969 22

7 LISBOA PORTUGAL 38.71667 -9.13333 12

3 BUDAPEST HUNGARY 47.49801 19.03991 0"


df <- read.table(text=x, 
                 header = F,
                 col.names=c('idx', 'City', 'Country', 'Latitude',  'Longitude', 'No..of.Samples'))

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
class(world)

## Produces the map of Europe ##
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_point(df, 
             mapping = aes(x= Longitude, y= Latitude,  size = No..of.Samples, color = Country), 
             fill="grey", alpha=0.3) + 
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-15, 55), ylim = c(34, 71), expand = FALSE)
```

It outputs:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for this. i keep on getting this error - Error in read.table(text = x, header = F, col.names = c("idx", "City",  : 
  more columns than column names

Comment: Do you know why this is happening? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm only using `df <- read.table(...)` because I don't have cities1_R.csv. If you replace with `df <- read.csv("cities1_R.csv")` it should work.